# "Owner of" vs. "owner for"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Should I say "I am the owner *of* ABC company" or I should say "I am the owner *for* ABC company"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a clear-cut situation fortunately. Using *of* is definitely correct here, whereas *for* is *not* correct.

> "I am the owner *of* abc company"

*Of* takes the role of the **possessive preposition** here. This is evidently appropriate, since the person possesses the company in some respect here.

Comment: More precise explanation. +1

Comment: I have come across "owner for this action / owner for my action". Is that incorrect too?

Comment: @JoseK: Outside of context, that makes no sense I'm afraid. I can't really see any scenario in which it is correct...

Answer (score 2):

I would go with:

> I am the owner of abc company

(a bit like: "I own abc company")

"owner" and "for" are not particularly linked together, "for" being here to introduce a purpose or function (and that wouldn't fit your example).
For instance:

> expropriate
>   verb (of the state) take (property) from its owner *for* public use or benefit.